# Lottie Animation in WinUI 3

Tags: winui-3, lottie

I am trying to implement lottie animation in a WinUI 3 app. Previously it was implemented in UWP. Where I used **AnimatedVisualPlayer** from **Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls** and **LottieVisualSource** from **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie**. The code snippet is shown here,

```
<AnimatedVisualPlayer Stretch="None">
    <LottieVisualPlayer UriSource="AnimatedImage.json" />
</AnimatedVisualPlayer>
```

But in WinUI3 I cannot find any alternate for **AnimatedVisualPlayer**. Is there any alternate way to use Lottie Animation in WinUI 3?

Answer (score 1):

You should need to install the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Lottie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/lottie-scenarios/getting_started_json) NuGet package.

```xml
<Page
...
    xmlns:lottie="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Lottie">

    <AnimatedVisualPlayer x:Name="LottiePlayer">
        <lottie:LottieVisualSource x:Name="LottieJsonSource" UriSource="ms-appx:///AnimatedVisuals/LottieLogo1.json"/>
    </AnimatedVisualPlayer>

</Page>
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew,
I don't think Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls and Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie can be used in WinUI3. For WinUI3 CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls and CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Lottie is used. But AnimatedVisualPlayer is not found in CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You don't need the namespace for "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" but you do need to install the **CommunityToolkit.WInUI.Lottie** and use the `LottieVisualSource`.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Seems like I can use AnimatedVisualPlayer without including Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls. Now animation is working. But I am not sure whether it is actual way to use AnimatedVisualPlayer in WinUI 3.

Comment: Another thing is, I had to set file location similar to like this,   `UriSource="ms-appx:///AnimatedVisuals\LottieLogo1.json"` notice the backward slash.

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell with the image you sent but I think you forgot to set "Build Action" as "Content" in the properties window.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/lottie-scenarios/getting_started_json

[image]